# Write rows from list to specific columns

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have gone through similar questions but am having trouble fitting this to my needs. I am reading a csv, creating a list and appending the list to a seperate csv.

```
with open('in_table.csv', 'rb') as vo:
    next(vo)    # skip header row
    reader = csv.reader(vo)
    vo_list = list(reader)
print vo_list

with open('out_table.csv', 'ab') as f:
    cf = csv.writer(f)
    for row in vo_list:
        cf.writerow(row)
```

I need to write the list starting at the second column and not the first, as the first column will contain separate information. What is the simplest way to do this?

Realistically I have another input CSV exactly like the first one and I need to put them both into the output file into a total of 4 columns. Like so:

```
Column1, join_count1, grid_id1, join_count2, grid_id2
Blah, 0, U24, 3, U24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the built-in `csv` package.  Also, you are opening CSV files as binary files, was that intentional?  CSVs should be text files by definition, but if yours are binary then please correct the flags below:

```py
import csv

with open("out_table.csv", "a+") as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    with open("in_table.csv") as in_file:
        reader = csv.reader(in_file)
        next(reader)  # skip the header
        for oid, join_count, grid_id in reader:
            writer.writerow([join_count, grid_id])
```